# confusion about creation of tabs in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Class2(object):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.welcomeScreen(self)


    def welcomeScreen(self,parent):
        print 'hello'
        self.centralwidget=QtGui.QWidget(parent)
        self.tabWidget=QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0,661,511))
        self.tab=QtGui.QWidget()
        self.lineEdit=QtGui.QLineEdit(self.tab)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab,"")
        self.tabWidget.show()



class Class1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Class1, self).__init__()
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        ex=Class2(self)





def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Class1()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Ok. So during the development of a small course management system, I came across a problem wherein I need to create tabs in class other than the one where the main window is defined. The following program scales down my problem.

The problem is in the `welcomeScreen(self, parent)` function wherein I need to add a tab widget.
The error is: `TypeError: QWidget(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Class2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
self.welcomeScreen(self)
```

should be

```
self.welcomeScreen(parent)
```

You are effectively passing the `Class2` object to `welcomeScreen` twice.

`self.welcomeScreen(b)` is equivalent to `Class2.welcomeScreen(self, b)`